# Why Manuel Diaz did not recognize Gillick as el Medellin/the ex-attorney?

Tags: plot-explanation, sicario

In Villeneuve's Sicario, every Sonora cartel's member who interacts with Gillick identifies him as el Medellin (Guillermo Diaz, Silvio) or the Juarez attorney (Alarcon).

Yet, when Gillick intercept him, Manuel Diaz doesn't realise who is dealing with. How is it considering he's cartel no 2?